# Rails server starts app in another folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I'm running a ruby on rails app on Ubuntu, but I found something weird.
I was developing an app that was giving an error that I could not solve, so I thought about removing the folder and restarting from a previous saved version, but when I run

```
rails server
```

the application being referenced is still the old one, even if it is in the Trash (the error message now references file in the Trash).
What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably [symlinked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link)

You'll be *much* better suited to running the likes of [`Phusion Passenger`](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/), which handles the serving of Rails applications for you.

Comment: I can explain how to install & run Phusion Passenger if you want - your question really needs more context & information though